# InceptionV3+LSTM activity recognition, accuracy grows for 10 epochs and then drops down

Tags: keras, lstm, yolo

I'm trying to build model to do activity recognition. 
Using InceptionV3 and backbone and LSTM for the detection, using pre-trained weights.

```
  train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
          'dataset/train',
          target_size=(1,224, 224),
          batch_size=batch_size,
          class_mode='categorical',  # this means our generator will only yield batches of data, no labels
          shuffle=True,
          classes=['PlayingPiano','HorseRiding','Skiing', 'Basketball','BaseballPitch'])

  validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
          'dataset/validate',
          target_size=(1,224, 224),
          batch_size=batch_size,
          class_mode='categorical',  # this means our generator will only yield batches of data, no labels
          shuffle=True,
          classes=['PlayingPiano','HorseRiding','Skiing', 'Basketball','BaseballPitch'])
  return train_generator,validation_generator
```

I train 5 classes so split my data into folders for train and validate.
This is my CNN+LSTM architecture

```
image = Input(shape=(None,224,224,3),name='image_input')
    cnn = applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False,
        pooling='avg')
    cnn.trainable = False
    encoded_frame = TimeDistributed(Lambda(lambda x: cnn(x)))(image)
    encoded_vid = LSTM(256)(encoded_frame)
    layer1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(encoded_vid)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.5)(layer1)
    layer2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(dropout1)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.5)(layer2)
    layer3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dropout2)
    dropout3 = Dropout(0.5)(layer3)
    outputs = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(dropout3)
 model = Model(inputs=[image],outputs=outputs)
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay = 1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(train_generator,validation_data = validation_generator,steps_per_epoch=300, epochs=nb_epoch,callbacks=callbacks,shuffle=True,verbose=1)
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
image_input (InputLayer)     (None, None, 224, 224, 3) 0
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, None, 2048)        0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               2360320
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               131584
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 325
_________________________________________________________________
```

Model compiles normally without problem. 
Problem starts during the training. It reaches val_acc=0.50 and then drops back to val_acc=0.30 and the loss just freeze on 0.80 and mostly don't move.

Here the logs from training, as you see the model for some tome improves and then just slowly drops down and later just freeze. 
Any idea what can be the reason?

```
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 1.56471 to 1.55652, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.02-0.28.h5
Epoch 3/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 219ms/step - loss: 1.5436 - acc: 0.3281 - val_loss: 1.5476 - val_acc: 0.2981

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 1.55652 to 1.54757, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.03-0.30.h5
Epoch 4/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 220ms/step - loss: 1.5109 - acc: 0.3593 - val_loss: 1.5284 - val_acc: 0.3588

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 1.54757 to 1.52841, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.04-0.36.h5
Epoch 5/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.4167 - acc: 0.4167 - val_loss: 1.4945 - val_acc: 0.3553

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 1.52841 to 1.49446, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.05-0.36.h5
Epoch 6/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.2941 - acc: 0.4683 - val_loss: 1.4735 - val_acc: 0.4443

Epoch 00006: val_loss improved from 1.49446 to 1.47345, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.06-0.44.h5
Epoch 7/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.2096 - acc: 0.5116 - val_loss: 1.3738 - val_acc: 0.5186

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 1.47345 to 1.37381, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.07-0.52.h5
Epoch 8/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.1477 - acc: 0.5487 - val_loss: 1.2337 - val_acc: 0.5788

Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 1.37381 to 1.23367, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.08-0.58.h5
Epoch 9/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.0809 - acc: 0.5831 - val_loss: 1.2247 - val_acc: 0.5658

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 1.23367 to 1.22473, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.09-0.57.h5
Epoch 10/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 1.0362 - acc: 0.6089 - val_loss: 1.1704 - val_acc: 0.5774

Epoch 00010: val_loss improved from 1.22473 to 1.17035, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.10-0.58.h5
Epoch 11/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.9811 - acc: 0.6317 - val_loss: 1.1612 - val_acc: 0.5616

Epoch 00011: val_loss improved from 1.17035 to 1.16121, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.11-0.56.h5
Epoch 12/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.9444 - acc: 0.6471 - val_loss: 1.1533 - val_acc: 0.5613

Epoch 00012: val_loss improved from 1.16121 to 1.15330, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.12-0.56.h5
Epoch 13/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.9072 - acc: 0.6650 - val_loss: 1.1843 - val_acc: 0.5361

Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 1.15330
Epoch 14/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.8747 - acc: 0.6744 - val_loss: 1.2135 - val_acc: 0.5258

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 1.15330
Epoch 15/500
300/300 [==============================] - 67s 222ms/step - loss: 0.8666 - acc: 0.6829 - val_loss: 1.1585 - val_acc: 0.5443

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 1.15330
Epoch 16/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 222ms/step - loss: 0.8386 - acc: 0.6926 - val_loss: 1.1503 - val_acc: 0.5482

Epoch 00016: val_loss improved from 1.15330 to 1.15026, saving model to ./weights_inception/Inception_V3.16-0.55.h5
Epoch 17/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.8199 - acc: 0.7023 - val_loss: 1.2162 - val_acc: 0.5288

Epoch 00017: val_loss did not improve from 1.15026
Epoch 18/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 222ms/step - loss: 0.8018 - acc: 0.7150 - val_loss: 1.1995 - val_acc: 0.5179

Epoch 00018: val_loss did not improve from 1.15026
Epoch 19/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.7923 - acc: 0.7186 - val_loss: 1.2218 - val_acc: 0.5137

Epoch 00019: val_loss did not improve from 1.15026
Epoch 20/500
300/300 [==============================] - 67s 222ms/step - loss: 0.7748 - acc: 0.7268 - val_loss: 1.2880 - val_acc: 0.4574

Epoch 00020: val_loss did not improve from 1.15026
Epoch 21/500
300/300 [==============================] - 66s 221ms/step - loss: 0.7604 - acc: 0.7330 - val_loss: 1.2658 - val_acc: 0.4861
```

Answer (score 0):

The model is starting to overfit. Ideally as you increase number of epochs training loss will decrease(depends on learning rate), if its not able to decrease may be your model can have a high bias for the data. You can use bigger model(more parameters or deeper model).

you can also to reduce the learning rate, if it still freezes then model may have a low bias.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. Yes, the problem was overfitting, so i made more aggresive dropout on LSTM, and it helped. But the accuracy on val_loss and acc_val still very low

```
    video = Input(shape=(None, 224,224,3))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3),
                weights="imagenet",
                include_top=False)
cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)
cnn.trainable = False
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(32, dropout=0.5, W_regularizer=l2(0.01), recurrent_dropout=0.5)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
dropout = Dropout(0.2)(hidden_layer)
outputs = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(dropout)
model = Model([video], outputs)
```

Here the logs

```
Epoch 00033: val_loss improved from 1.62041 to 1.57951, saving model to 
./weights_inception/Inception_V3.33-0.76.h5
Epoch 34/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.6301 - acc: 
0.9764 - val_loss: 1.6190 - val_acc: 0.7627

Epoch 00034: val_loss did not improve from 1.57951
Epoch 35/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.5907 - acc: 
0.9840 - val_loss: 1.5927 - val_acc: 0.7608

Epoch 00035: val_loss did not improve from 1.57951
Epoch 36/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.5783 - acc: 
0.9812 - val_loss: 1.3477 - val_acc: 0.7769

Epoch 00036: val_loss improved from 1.57951 to 1.34772, saving model to 
./weights_inception/Inception_V3.36-0.78.h5
Epoch 37/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.5618 - acc: 
0.9802 - val_loss: 1.6545 - val_acc: 0.7384

Epoch 00037: val_loss did not improve from 1.34772
Epoch 38/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.5382 - acc: 
0.9818 - val_loss: 1.8298 - val_acc: 0.7421

Epoch 00038: val_loss did not improve from 1.34772
Epoch 39/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 536ms/step - loss: 0.5080 - acc: 
0.9844 - val_loss: 1.7948 - val_acc: 0.7290

Epoch 00039: val_loss did not improve from 1.34772
Epoch 40/500
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 537ms/step - loss: 0.4800 - acc: 
0.9892 - val_loss: 1.8036 - val_acc: 0.7522
```